# Can web hosted javascript files be included in metro apps?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I want to include a web hosted piece of javascript to act as a widget in my metro application.  The goal would be to be able to maintain the state of the widget outside of the metro app so that a change to the widget code wouldn't require a repackaging and publishing to the app store.

e.g. (in my html file in the metro app)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://link.to.website/widget.js">
```

Comment: If you do this, make sure it works without internet access too, or it will probably get rejected from the store.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's important to understand the differences between the local and web context. Particular restrictions are documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465373.aspx -- what is worth noting is that you can **only** include external script files from pages running in the web context.

Also, your app always has to have a top level page that is in your package. This page must be in the local context and loaded via the ms-appx scheme. This outer page may choose to iframe pages loaded in the web context (via ms-appx-web for in-package files or via http/https for pages hosted on the web.)

What you should keep in mind is that even though you can load external script into a web context page, that script cannot access the Windows Runtime APIs. If you want your external script to be able to call WinRT, you can create a communication channel using the [HTML5 Web Messaging APIs](http://dev.w3.org/html5/postmsg/).

Answer (score 1):

If the metro apps lets you connect to the net *(if the app is not limited to local-only or similar)* that **should** be possible.

Also:

```
<script src="https://link.to.website/widget.js"></script>
```

not

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://link.to.website/widget.js">
```

Since JavaScript is the standard type for *script*, you do not have to declare that nowadays.